# mule 3, How can I send response from outbound-endpoint to another endpoint

Tags: mule

Is there a way to send the JSON response to another server as a request asynchronously (for example to monitor, etc...)
here is my mule flow

```
<flow name="loggingFlow1" doc:name="loggingFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${source.http.host}" port="${source.http.port}" doc:name="HTTP" responseTimeout="10000" />
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET" address="http://${dest.http.host}:${dest.http.port}#[header:INBOUND:http.request]" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP_GET" responseTimeout="10000" />

<async processingStrategy="Asynchronous_Processing_Strategy" doc:name="Async">
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" address="http://localhost:8080/Monitor/response" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</async>
</flow>
```

Comment: "Please help me" is kind of rude

Comment: What you've done _looks_ correct, what issue do you experience?

Comment: I got this exception: _java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream._ and when I add echo component before the async subflow and also object to string transformer at the first of the async subflow it works, however sometimes I get this exception:  _java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key can not be empty_ @DavidDossot

Comment: it works with 'echo-component' and 'object-to-string-transformer' as mentioned in previous comment. now the question is, why should I use 'echo-component'? Are there another way? @DavidDossot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any reason, it seems the `InputStream` produced by the first `http:outbound-endpoint` is read more than once.

Serializing this `InputStream` to a `String` with an `object-to-string-transformer` or a `byte[]` with an `object-to-byte-array-transformer` is the best option, the `echo-component` is a legacy one that is not very much used anymore.